# Update Cart Item quantity by customer quote id in custom API

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, api

I want to Update Cart Item quantity by `customer quote_id` in custom API.
I have tried below code but it's not work with Magento 2.3

```
$quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($quoteId);
                 $quoteItem = $quote->getItemById($itemId);
                $quoteItem->setQty((double) $qty);
                $quoteItem->save();
                $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
```

It's not working.

Comment: have you tried my answer?It's working code

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working for me

```
    $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);

    $item = $quote->getItemById($data['item_id']);
    $item->setQty($data['qty']);

    $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function updateCart($cartId,$itemId,$qty) {

    if($qty){
        $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->load($cartId); // \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory 
        $quoteItem = $quote->getItemById($itemId);
        $quoteItem->setQty($qty);
        $quoteItem->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
        $quoteItem->save();
        $quote->save();
    }
    return true;
}
```